# The real roots of $a_{10}x^{10}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ are $\le1.$ Then $a_{10} \frac{e^{10 x}}{10}+a_9\frac{e^{9 x}}9+\dots+a_1e^xa_0x, x>0,$ is monotonic?

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Suppose all roots of the polynomial  $$P(x)=a_{10}x^{10}+a_{9}x^{9}+\cdots+a_{1} x+a_{0}$$ are real and smaller than $1.$ Then, for any such polynomial, prove that the function $$f(x)=a_{10} \frac{e^{10 x}}{10}+a_{9} \frac{e^{9 x}}{9}+\cdots+a_{1} e^{x}+a_{0} x, x>0$$ is either increasing or decreasing.

Here is the outline of my attempt:

Firstly, I checked what $f'(x)$? I found, $$f'(x)=a_{10}e^{10x}+a_{9}e^{9x}+a_{8}e^{8x}+...+a_{2}e^{2x}+a_1e^x+a_0=P(e^x).$$ Since, $f'(x)=P(e^x)$, we now use the tiny detail that $x>0$. Due to this, $e^x>1$ as $e^x$ is an increasing function. Since, $P(e^x)\gt a_{10}+a_9+\cdots+a_1+a_0,$ this becomes clear that $f'(x)$ is greater than $P(1)$ (i.e the sum of the coefficients). We have two cases:
If $P(1)>0$, then, $f'(x)\gt 0$ and so, $f(x)$ is increasing.

If $P(1)<0$ then nothing can be said about $f(x)$ . So, how to conclude if $f(x)$ is decreasing in this case or not?

Comment: **Hint :** Your derivative is incorrect. You should find $f'(x)=P(e^x)$, and I am sure you can take it from here.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, note that $e^x>1$ for $x>0$ and you are done.

Comment: "... we don't have to worry about different values of $x$." What does that mean?

Comment: Specifically, if $f'$ changes signs between $x_1$ and $x_2,$ then $P(x)$ has a root between $e^{x_1}$ and $e^{x_2}.$

Comment: One more hint: as I noted $x>0$ implies $e^x>1$. Now consider whether $P(e^x) = 0$  is possible for $x>0$.

Comment: @IH No, that is never possible unless all the $a_i's$ are zero.

Comment: @AnneBauval I already used it, if you meant, I H 's hint.

Comment: @AnneBauval In order to have either of these inequalities $f'(x)\gt 0$ or $\lt 0$. The $\gt 0$ case is fine. But I get no result if $P(1)\lt 0$ as then $f'(x)$ is either $\gt 0$ or $<0$ .

Comment: $P(1)$ is irrelevant. What is important is that (you proved that) $f'(x)$ has constant sign for $x>0$, since it is continuous and never $=0$ (except in the trivial case $P=0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Wait, when did I prove it ?

Comment: See previous (updated) comment. Btw, your "$P(e^x)\gt a_{10}+a_9+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$" has no reason to hold. The $a_i$'s are not assumed $\ge0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval By any chance, did you mean as $f'(x)$ is continuous so, $f'(x)\gt 0$ $\forall x\in \Bbb R$ or $f'(x)\lt 0$ $\forall x\in \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: This is what I wrote *explicitely* (more that "meant"), but not $\forall x\in\Bbb R.$ I wrote for $x>0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Is that a property for continuous functions ?

Comment: This is the IVT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: @AnneBauval Wait, if I am not wrong, then IVT just says, that if $f$ is continuous and has a minimum and maximum image, then $f$ attains all values between those max and min images as well ? But then how does that relate to $f'(x)$ ?

Comment: You are partially wrong. IVT is not about extrema. It only says that a continuous function on an interval (like $f'$ on $(0,+\infty)$) attains all values between each two values attained. So, again: "$f′(x)$ has constant sign for $x>0$, since it is continuous and never $=0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x)=a_{10} (e^{x})^{10}+a_{9} (e^{x})^{9}+\cdots+a_{1} e^{x}+a_{0} =P(e^x) \tag{1}$$

As all roots $(r_i)_{i=1,..,10}$ of $P(x)$ are reals , we can write
$$P(x)=a_{10}\prod_{i=1}^{10}(x-r_i)$$

From $(1),(2)$ and from the assumption that the roots are all less than $1$

$$f'(x)=a_{10}\prod_{i=1}^{10}\underbrace{(e^x-r_i)}_{\ge1-r_i >0}\hspace{2cm}\text{for }x\ge0$$
$$\Longrightarrow  \text{sign}(f'(x))=\text{sign}(a_{10}) \hspace{2cm}\text{for }x\ge0 $$

We deduce that $f(x)$ is monotonic  (if $a_{10}>0$, $f(x)$ is increasing. If $a_{10}<0$, $f(x)$ is decreasing).

Q.E.D

Answer (score -1):

Seems like my hint doesn't lead readily understanding of a solution I intended. So I'm posting details here.

$f^\prime (x) = P(e^x)$ as noted by OP.

By the assumption that all the roots of $P(x)$ is real and smaller than $1$ and the fact that $e^x >1$ for any $x>0$, we conclude that $f^\prime (x) = P(e^x)$ cannot be $0$ for any $x>0$. To understand this, suppose $P(e^x)=0$ for any $x=\alpha>0$. Then $x=e^\alpha$ is a root of $P(x)$. However, $\alpha >0$ implies $e^\alpha>1$. That means $P(x)$ has a root which is larger than $1$. This is a contradiction.

Since $f^\prime(x)$ cannot be equal to $0$ for $x>0$ and is continuous, we must have either $f^\prime (x)<0$ for all $x>0$ or $f^\prime (x)>0$ for all $x>0$. The former implies $f(x)$ is increasing on $x>0$ and the latter implies $f(x)$ is decreasing on $x<0$.

Comment: @I H Did you mean this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695047/the-real-roots-of-a-10x10-cdotsa-1xa-0-are-le1-then-a-10-frac#comment9934541_4695047 ?

Comment: I thought my two comments are good enough for you to complete the rest of the argument. But it seems logic here is still a bit complicated for you. So, I thought it would be better to elaborate than just leaving another brief comment.